# Redis pubsub retry logic

Tags: ioredis

I had thought that the retry strategy option was actually for dealing with and retrying errors that might happen inside the logic at the subscriber side e.g. some 3rd party service returned a 429 or some system intermittently down, but it seems to be more to do with redis itself being up.

Assuming my subscriber throws an error and that I would like to retry my logic say, 3 times with a slight backoff what is the general way to handle this with redis pubsub?

is there a config option that automatically handles this? or do I implement a local try,catch,retry inside the subscriber and save to a dead letter label after max failures ? or should I explicity put message back on to queue etc

```
const options = {
      host: config.redisConnection,
      password: config.redisPassword,
      port: 6379,
      retryStrategy: (times) => Math.min(times * 50, 2000),
      tls: { checkServerIdentity: () => undefined },
    };
  
    const { RedisPubSub } = require("graphql-redis-subscriptions");
    const Redis = require("ioredis");
  
    return new RedisPubSub({
      publisher: new Redis(options),
      subscriber: new Redis(options),
    });
```